# Twig template engine

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller, twig

Well i have strange problem with Twig render (i'm using it with MVC framework).
when i access my page with hardcoded route like:

```
$router->add('projects', ['controller' => 'Projects', 'action' => 'index']);
```

everything works fine... my index.html file is fully extended by twig's template file base.html

BUT when i try use universal route like

```
$router->add('{controller}/{action}');
```

so in address bar i type siteName/projects/index my page is loaded with content only, completely without CSS ...

Comment: What the console say?

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" on my JS CSS IMG files lol ;x

Comment: i should check console sooner ... i fixed these error... had many incorrect paths like: src="js/skills.js" where should be src="/js/skills.js" ... so skipping forward slashes at beginning of paths caused so many problems :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i should check console sooner ... i fixed these error... had many incorrect paths like: src="js/skills.js" where should be src="/js/skills.js" ... so skipping forward slashes at beginning of paths caused so many problems :D